# Cannot output a foreign key object in core 2.2, even though the data entries seems correct

Tags: sql, asp.net-core, .net-core, foreign-keys

I have a complex type (Dorm) which has a address field (Address type), but when i debug a function on the Dorms it has the address field = null, even though when i open the database explorer the addressID foreign key is filled correctly.

I have made sure the SQL is proper, but am now unsure where to look for the mistake

The dbcontext is as follows, and i have an idea that this could be where the problem is

```
namespace OptimalHousing.Models
{
    public class OptimalHousingContext : DbContext
    {
        public OptimalHousingContext (DbContextOptions<OptimalHousingContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<OptimalHousing.Models.Dorm> Dorm { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OptimalHousing.Models.Address> addresses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The dorm sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Dorm] (
    [id]        INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [addressid] INT            NULL,
    [dormName]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [dormUrl]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Dorm] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_Dorm_Address_addressid] FOREIGN KEY ([addressid]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Addresses] ([id])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Dorm_addressid]
    ON [dbo].[Dorm]([addressid] ASC);
```

Addresses sql

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[addresses] (
    [id]           INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [street]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [streetNumber] INT            NOT NULL,
    [zipCode]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [longitude]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [latitude]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_addresses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
);
```

My classes:

```
public class Dorm
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public Dorm() {}
        [DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "No address")]
        public Address address { get; set; }
        public string dormName { get; set; }

        public string dormUrl { get; set; }
    }
public class Address
    {
        [Key]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string street { get; set; }
        public int streetNumber { get; set; }
        public int zipCode { get; set; }

        public string longitude { get; set; }
        public string latitude { get; set; }
}
```

Please let me know if some other code is needed to solve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JOIN queries are not issued automatically. You have to make that happen by telling EF to load the relationship eagerly or explicitly. You can also opt to enable lazy-loading, but that is really not recommended.

**Eager loading**

```
var dorms = await _context.Dorms.Include(x => x.Address).ToListAsync();
```

**Explicit loading**

```
var dorms = await _context.Dorms.ToListAsync();
foreach (var dorm in dorms)
{
    await _context.Entry(dorm).Reference(x => x.Address).LoadAsync();
}
```

Obviously, earger loading is a lot more efficient as it will issue a true JOIN at the database. Explicit loading will result in a separate queries for each item in the list, but can be useful in situations where you want to conditionally load or not a relationship.

The last option is lazy-loading. It requires two things:

1. The property must be `virtual`, i.e. `public virtual Address Address { get; set; }`
2. You must turn on lazy-loading via `UseLazyLoadingProxies()`, when configuring your context in `ConfigureServices`.

   ```
   services.AddDbContext<OptimalHousingContext>(o =>
       o.UseLazyLoadingProxies()
        .UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("OptimalHousing")));
   ```

With lazy-loading, the relationship will be loaded just-in-time when the property is accessed. This is why the `virtual` keyword is required on the property. EF will create a dynamic proxy class that overrides your reference and collection properties to add a custom getter that attempts to pull from the object cache, and if that fails, issue a query to get the related item(s) instead.

However, this is *highly* inefficient, especially when dealing with lists of things. It will issue a separate query for each relationship for each item in the list, often resulting in N+1 queries or sometimes even N(N+1) queries. The more relationships and the deeper your object graph, the worse it gets. Your best bet is always to just eagerly load anything you want to work with.

Comment: It works for my function as asked in the question :) But can i possibly do something like this then: `@Html.DisplayFor(ModelItem => item.address) ` in my html

Comment: Sure? I mean functionally that should work, if you've actually got some data in `address`, but `DisplayFor` is a templated helper, and I don't think it can handle rendering an entire object without an actual template for that type. `EditorFor` can, but, it basically just adds an input and label for all the properties on the type, which works as a basic default. There's not a really a default *display* of multiple values.